# View all files under one SharePoint document library

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I have many levels of folders created under a SharePoint document library.
I know SharePoint online can display files under one folder using a custom view (show or hide some columns).

Is there some way to flatten files from all folders/subfolders under a document library and view all of them on a same page on the SharePoint site?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can modify the current view and select "Show all items without folders" in the **Folders**.

[image]