# Power Automate export excel file automatically

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate

I'm trying to get excel file from sharepoint. Event if I add an action Sharepoint Get Items I get in the end not that I wanted to. The sharepoint folder structure can be complex. Now I want to make the Export to Excel autoamatic. If I do that manually I get what I want.

[image]

Comment: So let me get this straight, you want to export a list to Excel?

Comment: Yes, do far I was able to save a file but the contens are limited. I want to download everythicng that inside that folder

Comment: A list isn’t a folder. A folder is a folder and a list is a list. So sorry, but does that mean you want all of the list data as well as the folders and files?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to create a view on your list with the settings:
**Folder > Show all items without folders**? There is already a question about it: [View all files under one SharePoint document library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56452663/view-all-files-under-one-sharepoint-document-library)

How to create a view: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-change-or-delete-a-view-of-a-list-or-library-27ae65b8-bc5b-4949-b29b-4ee87144a9c9

That way, all of the list items will be displayed at the same level (flat hierarchy). This view could be dedicated to the Excel export: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/export-to-excel-from-sharepoint-or-lists-bfb2ea48-6118-4fa9-abb6-cced9424e5d9

Beware of the limit of 5,000 items per view.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I found a blog about this by Bijay, a Microsoft MVP for SharePoint. The article describes the relevant operation steps in detail, which may be helpful to you.
https://www.spguides.com/export-sharepoint-list-items-to-excel-using-power-automate/